# SSIS package check if record exist then update else insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, ssis

I am creating this SSIS import package for about 10 tables , I am still new to this so I really appreciate any help I can get.
I need to compare my Excel source to this ~10 tables to see if any record exists ,if it exists then update it or else insert it. I am struggling on how to check on various tables where they all have auto-incremented PK. If one record doesn't exist how can I insert it and make sure the other tables have the foreign keys(auto-incremented primary key of tables) updated as well.Meaning the relationship of each record that have been divided into so many tables are tact.
My plan for the package:

```
    Excel source
    Look up transformer
    Data conversion transformer
    derived column transformer
    multicast
    OLE DB destination
```

Please advise on how I should go about, and the order I should follow for my transformers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm ok firstly get the excel source into an sql staging table first (truncate before loading) then you could consider using the sql merge statement via an execute sql task to merge the data into the end tables. This will allow you to insert if the record dosent exist. You may need to lookup the foreign keys before running the merge. Are you able to post details of the 10 tables and import csv?

Comment: Thanks Greg! The tables would be like Location Type, Location, Area,District, Sector, Site, Building, Unit, Assets. Each record in the import file has all or most field associated with each other.